# Meaning of "It would be ungenerous to affect not to know that your self-denial is to be referred to your consideration for her father"

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, formality, charles-dickens

> It would be ungenerous to affect not to know that your self-denial is to be referred to your consideration for her father

Chapter 10, A Tale of Two Cities.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your question to include an explanation of why it comes up and to include your prior research on the matter. In this case, what is it that you find confusing and why, and what words did you look up or what other references did you consult before asking?

Comment: Note that the next thing Doctor Manette (the speaker) says is "Her father thanks you". Bearing in mind that he *is in fact* the father it's probably fair to say that the *overall meaning* of these words is that he's uncomfortable with the whole situation, and the need for him to explicitly state how he feels about it. So he's being deliberately circumlocutory in order to "distance" himself from his words.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves textual analysis rather than focusing on a single point. It would sit better on the Literature.SE site (there is a 'meaning' tag).

Answer (score 2):

Just translate parts of the sentence to simpler words, or more-obvious words, or in some cases place-holders, as follows.

- It would be ungenerous  → It would be mean
- to affect not to know → to pretend to not know → to pretend [not]
- that your self-denial → that your X
- is to be referred to → is to be attributed to → is because of
- your consideration for her father → your regard for Y

This gives  “It would be mean to pretend that your X is [not] because of your regard for Y”.  Roughly paraphrased, it says “I know you did X because of Y”.

*Edit:* I accidentally left out a *not*.  I show it in brackets to indicate that it is moved to a later position in the simplified sentence.

Comment: Surely to *affect **not** to know* paraphrases as *deny*, not *pretend/claim*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my error; see edit

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing "affect" being used this way which probably created confusion for me. Thanks a lot for pointing  for that out.

Comment: Also, read up on [overnegation](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1925) and [misnegation](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4407).

Comment: It is a separate, and less common, meaning of _affect_. See "affect v.2" [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=affect&searchmode=none).

Answer (score 0):

“It would be ungenerous to affect not to know that your self-denial is to be referred to your consideration for her father"

Translated 2023
It would be a shame to deny your doubt is not merely based on how you feel about her dad

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).